# Can you force a hyperlink click event on page load

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I've implemented a menu for my asp.net page containing some hyperlinks and loading different contents on their clicks, it's using jquery on behind for it's style mostly and it is working fine. But the problem is, what if a refer to this menu from the outside, i can refer to each of the menu items, i pass parameters on querystring, now i can find which item is clicked but how  can i force that hyperlink menu item to be clicked on page load. I'm specifing just their navigation urls, how can i specify that if something is passed in querystring than that specific menu item should be forced clicked on pageload.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

The real question lies can you cuase a hyperlink click event?

Now I'm using 
`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page),"test1", "<script>document.getElementById('linkButtonId').click();</script>");` but still nothing desirable happens, seems that this row has no effect at all.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the functionality being executed is client side or server side, it might be a good idea to create a function that will accept the id or something of the menu item being clicked and then handle it appropriately.

Thus all the menu items will call the same function.  And since you have the parameters in the query string just pass them through to the function which will handle it accordingly and display the correct content?

Answer (score 0):

You need a bit of separation...

Whatever your click does can be moved into a function, then you can call the function on the click of the menu - but you can also call the function at other times as well.

Before:

```
<a ... onclick="alert('hello');">Click Me</a>
```

After:

```
<a ... onclick="fnSayHello();">Click Me</a>
...
var fnSayHello = function() { alert('hello'); };
fnSayHello();
```